# Decomposition of augmentation ideal in a group ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring and $G$ be a finite group with invertible order in $R$. Assume that the augmentation ideal $\Delta (G)$ of group ring $RG$ has a decomposition $M_1\oplus M_2\oplus \cdots M_k$ as an $R$-module and each $M_i$ has the property $P$ as an $R$-module (for example, $P$ could be being indecomposable as an $R$-module). There is a natural question:

Is there such a decomposition for $\Delta (G)$ as an $RG$-module? Is there a relevance? Does decomposition of $\Delta (G)$ as an $R$-module give us some information about decomposition of $\Delta (G)$ as an $RG$-module?

We know that if $N$ is an $RG$-submodule of $RG$ and $N$ is a direct summand of $RG$ as an $R$-module, then by Lemma 2.2 of [1], $N$ is a direct summand of $RG$ as an $RG$-module.

[1] M. Tamer Kosan, Tsiu-Kwen Lee, Yiqiang Zhou, On Modules Over Group Rings, Algebr. Represent. Theor. (2014) 17:87–102.

Comment: If the order is G is invertible then an RG-module is projective as an RG-module iff it is as an R-module.  I'm not sure what else you get.

Comment: Note the augmentation ideal is a summand in RG

Comment: Are you assuming M_i is an RG-module or an R-module?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Each M_i is an R-module. The augmentation ideal just have a decomposition to R-modules.

Comment: As an R-module it is a direct sum of $|G|-1$ copies of $R$ so you seem to want things like R semiperfect mais RG semiperfect under your assumption.  I think that is true

Comment: It is right. But R can be decompose to R-modules! For instance, R be a direct sum of uniform R-modules.

Comment: If R is semiperfect (so Krull Schmidt applies to R) then RG is semiperfect and so even without order G invertible you get the decomposition into projective indecomposables for RG and hence for the augmentation ideal is order G is invertible

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. R is an arbitrary ring in general. I mean to use the R-module decomposition of augmentation to identify or characterize the ring RG. When you have a condition on R (e.g. semiperfect), and because G is a finite group with invertible order in R, that condition is most likely inherited to RG. I am looking for identifying the ring RG only with helping of R-module decomposition of augmentation ideal.